# Efficient lazy ByteString generation, using random ByteString as an example

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation, bytestring

There seems to be some impediment to efficient lazy `ByteString` generation by recursion. To demonstrate this, the chosen task is to make a lazy random `ByteString`. (Random number generation is just a reasonably meaningful operation, i.e. a placeholder for any other recursion that might be of interest.)

Here are two attempts to create a random lazy `ByteString` of fixed length `n`. They allocate huge amounts of heap. First some imports:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import Data.Word8
import System.Random
```

Now the function that uses [`cons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:cons):

```
lazyRandomByteString1 :: Int -> StdGen -> BSL.ByteString
lazyRandomByteString1 n g = fst3 $ iter (BSL.empty, n, g) where
    fst3 (a, _, _) = a
    iter (bs', n', g') =
        if n' == 0 then (bs', 0, g')
        else iter (w `BSL.cons` bs', n'-1, g'') where
            (w, g'') = random g' :: (Word8, StdGen)
```

The same, just using [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:unfoldr) is shorter, but almost as bad as the above:

```
lazyRandomByteString2 :: Int -> StdGen -> BSL.ByteString
lazyRandomByteString2 n g = BSL.unfoldr f (n, g) where
    f :: (Int, StdGen) -> (Int, StdGen)
    f (n', g') =
        if n' == 0 then Nothing
        else Just (w, (n'-1, g'')) where
            (w, g'') = random g' :: (Word8, StdGen)
```

Within what's provided by [`Data.ByteString.Lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:cons) these are all the available options to create `ByteStrings` by recursion.

Next, turn to [`Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.0.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Builder.html#t:Builder), it was built to build lazy `ByteStrings`, surely this must be more efficient:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder (Builder, toLazyByteString, word8)

lazyRandomByteString3 :: Int -> StdGen -> BSL.ByteString
lazyRandomByteString3 n g = toLazyByteString builder where
    builder :: Builder
    builder = fst3 $ iter (mempty, n, g) where
        fst3 (a, _, _) = a
        iter :: (Builder, Int, StdGen) -> (Builder, Int, StdGen)
        iter (b, n', g') =
            if n' == 0 then (b, 0, g')
            else iter (b <> (word8 w), n'-1, g'') where
                (w, g'') = random g' :: (Word8, StdGen)
```

But it isn't.

`Builder` really should be able to do this efficiently, shouldn't it? What is wrong with `lazyRandomByteString3`?

The source code is on [github](https://github.com/mcmayer/lazy-random-bytestring).

Comment: How are you compiling and testing this?

Comment: Have a look at the github repo. I use the profiler.

Comment: When I compile & run this, I see `157,396,032 bytes maximum residency` which seems pretty reasonable for a million-byte array.  The profile shows that 78% of allocations are in `random`.  If you want to compare your 3 recursion patterns, it might help to use a less-expensive placeholder function.

Comment: So you are looking at the total allocation (as indicated by your 'grep') instead of the maximum residency?  Are you mistaking this for the maximum residency?

Comment: ok, total alloc may not be a good benchmark. But it's too high, anyway. I expect some kind of fusion happening, and much faster runtimes. I'll try with a different placeholder function.

Comment: What is the basis for your expectation?  You're generating 1 byte for every step of StdGen which consumes around 152 bytes each step for 1G allocated just for the RNG prior to optimizations (which are inhibited by profiling).

Comment: I swapped in a dumb old RNG, and I enforced some strictness, but that makes no difference. When you run this with 1G bytes, no profiler, you'll see that it will exhaust your RAM. In the end, this should use 32kB (chunk size, I believe) plus some overhead.